# ngFor not displaying when only 1 item returned in array

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I have a **json array** that I collect from a REST API call looks as follows:

```
[ 
    {"id":1,"title":"Title One","author":"Auth One"},
    {"id":2,"title":"Title Two","author":"Auth Two"},
    {"id":3,"title":"Another Title","author":"Another author"}
]
```

I created a class **posts.model.ts** to represent what a post consists of:

```
export class Post {
    id: Number;
    title: string;
    author: string;
}
```

My **view-component.component.html** (I know horrible name I am sorry) looks as follows:

```
<p>
    Post ID:<br>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="id">
</p>
<p>
    <button (click)="search()">Search</button>
</p>
<div *ngIf="PostList">
    <div *ngFor="let post of PostList">
        Post ID: {{post.id}}<br>
        Post Title: {{post.title}}<br>
        Post Author: {{post.author}}
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my **view-component.component.ts** like this

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post } from './post.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-component',
  templateUrl: './view-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-component.component.css']
})
export class ViewComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('post') post: Post;
  id: string = "";
  PostList: any = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  search() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/posts/' + this.id)
    .subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.PostList = data;
      console.log("This is what I got back = " + JSON.stringify(data));
    })
  }

}
```

What I have observed is that when I click the button with nothing in the input field (I want all the posts to be returned (this works as expected and I get a full list of all the posts)).

However when I enter for example the number "2" in the input field and click the button I expect to only see the 2nd post ("Title Two" "Auth Two") displayed, however nothing is displayed.

As you can see in the ".ts" file I am writing out to the console the string I get back in the search() function.  When I search for the 2nd post I do get the following :

`This is what I got back = {"id":2,"title":"Title Two","author":"Auth Two"}`

However, nothing is displayed on the html page.

Comment: It's coz you are getting a single object not an array with one object. You might be getting an error as well for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you return an `object`. You need to return an `array` with 1 element from your back end:

`[{"id":2,"title":"Title Two","author":"Auth Two"}]`

Comment: Ahh ... This makes perfect sense.  I am using "JSON Server" as a Fake Rest API.  When I look at the raw data that is being returned I see that in the one instance the response is an array, however when only one record is returned only an object is returned and not an array with one object inside.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, its a common mistake with rest apis, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would implement it:

- I would use `interface` instead of `class` like so

  ```
  export interface Post {
      id: Number;
      title: string;
      author: string;
  }
  ```
- I would then use the created interface in the array declaration `PostList: Post[];` and I would also leave it undefined so that the `<div *ngIf='PostList'>` works because the check will only be false if the array is undefined.
- I would also use the interface when calling the API `this.http.get<Post[]>` and use it again when receiving data from the API `.subscribe((data: Post[]) =>`

  ```
  this.http.get<Post[]>('http://localhost:3000/posts/' + this.id)
      .subscribe((data: Post[]) => {
        this.PostList = data;
        console.log("This is what I got back = " + JSON.stringify(data));
      })
  ```

Please don't hesitate to reach me out for further assistance if needed.

Comment: Thanks Tariq.  I still get the issue I had before as the return is not an array just a single object, however I really appreciate the suggestions and changes you recommended.  Is this a matter of style or are there other benefits for choosing an interface over a class?